# MinimumOSVersion in bundle FoxitRDK.framework is invalid

Tags: ios, foxit

We have Foxit in our iOS app, how to treat this, and get app to App Store?

> ERROR ITMS-90362: "Invalid Info.plist value. The value for the key
>   'MinimumOSVersion' in bundle PFB.app/Frameworks/FoxitRDK.framework is
>   invalid. The minimum value is 8.0"

[image]